# load a php form in the same page using jquery and ajax

Tags: php, forms, jquery

I want a function that loads the values from a PHP form and show the result in a div in the same file ;

I have a form in PHP file with the code bellow :

```
<?php

 echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js'></script>";
echo"<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>";


echo"<form method='post' action=''  >";
echo " <select name='mat'><option value=''>Choose: </option>";
echo"<option >hello</option>";
echo"</select>";
echo"<input type = 'submit'  value='next' onclick='submit();' />";
echo"</form>";

echo"<div id ='result'> </div>";
?>
```

and the function in `script.js` is :

```
function submit() {
    $(function () {
        var mat = "mat";
        var dataString = 'mat=' + mat;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "check.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function (res) {
                goToByScroll("result");
                $('#result').html("<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>").hide().fadeIn(2500, function () {
                    $('#result').html(res + "<br /><br /> Finished");
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```

and the `check.php` that load the values is :

```
<?php 
function safe($value)
{
    htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
    return $value;
}
if (isset($_POST['mat'])) {
    $mat = safe($_POST['mat']);
    echo ($mat);
}
elseif (!isset($_POST['mat'])) {
    header('Location: error?mat=notfound');
} ?>
```

But when I click next in the fist PHP file, it doesn't show anything, can you find the error?

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing the `$(function(){ ..` inside the `submit` function. You have to remove that line so you will get this:

```
function submit() {
    var mat = "mat";
    var dataString = 'mat=' + mat;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "check.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(res) {
            goToByScroll("result");
            $('#result').html("<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>").hide().fadeIn(2500, function() {
                $('#result').html(res + "<br /><br /> Finished");
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Try add `console.log(res)` to the success function and see if you get anything back.